# How to give subquery with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**DB QUERY:**

```
Select * from deviceCategory Where deviceCategory.subCategoryId IN('Select subCategoryId From subCategory where subCategoryName=$value');
```

This is the raw db query I have tried. But its not working. What I want here is, Firstly I need to get the `subCategoryId` from `subCategory` table based on the value passed to the controller. With the selected id I need to compare it with another table for the same matches of id and fetch the details of that table.

**Controller code:**

```
public function checkDeviceCategory($value)
{    
 $users=DB::select('SELECT * FROM deviceCategory WHERE 
 deviceCategory.subCategoryId IN (SELECT subCategoryId FROM 
 subCategory WHERE subCategoryName=$value)');
 echo $users;
}
```

SCRIPT code;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.checkDeviceCategory').click(function() {
var value=$(this).text();
if(value)
{
 window.location='checkDeviceCategory/' +value;

}
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the value passed to controller.

Comment: You know that PHP variables never get evaluated in single-quoted strings?

Comment: yes..How to correct it

Comment: You use double-quotes if you want variables evaluated to their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries):

```
$sub = DB::table('subCategory')
    ->where('subCategoryName', '=', $value)
    ->pluck('subCategoryId');

$users = DB::table('deviceCategory')
    ->whereIn('subCategoryId', $sub)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry,It throws an error.  **Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/AdminPanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 131 and defined**->error

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string-->now it throws like this